# iPhone 7 deactivated – Won't get recognized on any Mac/PC

Tags: iphone, charging

I've bought a used iPhone 7 two weeks ago and later found out that the proximity sensor didn't work. So while being in my pocket, it apparently tried too many codes and hence is deactivated now.

Now when I tried to connect the iPhone to my 2012 MacBook Pro, I realized that it does not connect in any way (a glimpse into system info confirms that there is no device connected). Charging via a AC works, though. Strangely, whenever I connect the iPhone to my Mac, there is a slight vibration on the phone, but it won't charge or anything.

So far I've tried two MacBooks and several cables, I've updated my MacBook to macOS Mojave, I've force-reset the iPhone and put it in DFU, nothing works. Two weeks ago I was able to do a backup via iTunes, so everything was working properly.  I'm starting to get a bit desperate, so has anyone an idea?

My search on the Internet has not yielded anything so far.

Answer (score 1):

Try erasing the phone from Find my iPhone on iCloud.com. The phone thinks it has been stolen.